# Stuck at this step sudo make import-sql area=planet-latest

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, tileserver

As described here: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/stuck-at-this-step-sudo-make-import-sql-area-planet-latest/6843 ,

I followed the indications found here: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/basemap-tileserver-gl-openmaptiles-ubuntu-22-04

I first tried the whole process for a small data, the Isle of Man, and everything works fine

[image]

But with the data of the entire world, I'm stuck at this sub-step, of `step 8` :

```
root@vmi1046457:~/openmaptiles# sudo make import-sql area=planet-latest

Time: 1.587 ms
psql:/sql/parallel/water__waterway.sql:1016: NOTICE:  schema "waterway_important" already exists, skipping
CREATE SCHEMA
Time: 9.567 ms
psql:/sql/parallel/water__waterway.sql:1027: NOTICE:  relation "changes" already exists, skipping
CREATE TABLE
Time: 39.958 ms
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 197.301 ms
psql:/sql/parallel/water__waterway.sql:1048: NOTICE:  relation "updates" already exists, skipping
CREATE TABLE
Time: 1.386 ms
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 10.781 ms
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 54.163 ms
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 13.839 ms
CREATE TRIGGER
Time: 159.570 ms
CREATE TRIGGER
Time: 1100.683 ms (00:01.101)
CREATE TRIGGER
Time: 42.035 ms
CREATE TRIGGER
Time: 71.131 ms
CREATE FUNCTION
Time: 18.919 ms
```

This step is very `cpu-intentive` : the 10 vcpus usage is within the this range :75% - 99%

[image]

The `VPS` I'm using of a Cloud Service Provider has the following features:

```
A 10 core CPU
60 GB RAM
1.6 TB Intel Optane SSD
```

Are these technical features enough for importing into `postgresql` DB the data of the entire world?
What can I do to make this step : `sudo make import-sql` speed up and finish?

Comment: cross-post: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/stuck-at-this-step-sudo-make-import-sql-area-planet-latest/6843

Comment: @scai is this an issue? If this is the case, I remove this post from `stackoverflow`. Please let me know

Comment: It is an issue if you don't mention it. Because then people start to answer questions that have already been answered elsewhere. This is bad. So please mention if you already posted the same question at a different place.

Comment: @scai Ok I updated this post above mentioning the question in `osm community`. Looking forward to your kind help